# Estimating shipping rate on product details page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, product-page

I want to display estimate shipping on detail page. User will check shipping cost from product detail page like same as cart page.

Any one have complete this function. Kindly give your suggestion on this.

Thanks

Comment: This is M1 code but you can still make it as a reference: http://2hatslogic.com/blog/estimating-shipping-rate-on-product-details-page-in-magento/

Comment: Before asking a new question, accept your previous answers to clean the community, I can see from your account there are lots of question which are unaccepted @S H Patel

Comment: Give me lists of my questions which you are see in my account. May I not asking any questions without accept previous question answer?

Comment: Its not my cup of tea to give you list , you can directly check into your account :), yes of course you can asked thousands of question without accepting the answers and its your privilege. But to to clean the community Its our duty @SHPatel

Comment: And even to clean the community, moderators are organizing the MageStackDay event, you can read more info about it by http://magestackday.com/ @SHPatel